# ¿Por qué cuando paso punteros como parámetros de un constructor, no se ve la información que llevan cuando el objeto es creado?

Tags: c++

Este programa compila y ejecuta pero no muestra la información del objeto creado, simplemente sale 0 (o vacío en el caso del string)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Automotor {
private:
    //atributos
    string tipo{};
    short int ruedas{};
    short int motor{};
    
    //pointers de los atributos
    string *p_tipo = &tipo;
    short int *p_ruedas = &ruedas;
    short int *p_motor = &motor;
    
public:
    //métodos
    void info_base(){

        cout<<"Tipo de vehículo: "<<*p_tipo<<endl<<"N° de ruedas: "<<*p_ruedas<<endl<<"Motor: "<<*p_motor<<" cilindros"<<endl;
    }

    //constructores
   
    Automotor(string p_tipo, short int p_ruedas, short int p_motor){
        p_tipo = p_tipo;
        p_ruedas = p_ruedas;
        p_motor = p_motor;
        info_base();
    };
    
};

int main(){
    Automotor("Dobletroque",10,6); 
    cout<<"Programa finalizado con éxito"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prueba a cambiarle el nombre a los argumentos de tu función constructor. Cuando escribes `p_tipo = p_tipo;` te estás refiriendo al argumento de la función y quieres que a la izquierda de la expresión esté el atributo de tu objeto: `*(this->p_tipo) = p_tipo;`.

Comment: Eso lo solucionó. Muchas gracias

Comment: El código no funciona como esperas porque los parámetros ocultan a los atributos porque se llaman igual.

Answer (score 1):

El error está en esta parte del código:

```
Automotor(string p_tipo, short int p_ruedas, short int p_motor){
    p_tipo = p_tipo;
    p_ruedas = p_ruedas;
    p_motor = p_motor;
    info_base();
};
```

*Es que estás pasando* **[punteros](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)** *al constructor en lugar de los valores a los que están apuntando.*

Al pasar el puntero como parámetro al constructor y asignar los valores a los que apuntan los punteros, los punteros no están siendo modificados; lo que está ocurriendo es que aún continúan apuntando a los valores originales.

Y los intentos de cambios realizados dentro del constructor solo serán una copia local de los valores señalados por los punteros y no los valores originales fuera del constructor.

Esta es la corrección:

```
  Automotor(string* p_tipo, short int* p_ruedas, short int* p_motor) {
     tipo = *p_tipo;
     ruedas = *p_ruedas;
     motor = *p_motor;
    }
```

Es un desreferenciado para obtener los valores señalados por los punteros.
*Complete* `code`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Automotor {
private:
    
    string tipo{};
    short int ruedas{};
    short int motor{};

public:
   
    Automotor(string* p_tipo, short int* p_ruedas, short int* p_motor) {
        tipo = *p_tipo;
        ruedas = *p_ruedas;
        motor = *p_motor;
    }

  
    void info_base() {
        cout << "Tipo de vehículo: " << tipo << endl;
        cout << "N° de ruedas: " << ruedas << endl;
        cout << "Motor: " << motor << " cilindros" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    string tipo = "Dobletroque";
    short int ruedas = 10;
    short int motor = 6;

    string* p_tipo = &tipo;
    short int* p_ruedas = &ruedas;
    short int* p_motor = &motor;
    Automotor carro(p_tipo, p_ruedas, p_motor);
    carro.info_base();

    cout << "Programa finalizado con éxito" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda